# Cloud Computing Lab Specifications

Tags: cloud, eucalyptus, opennebula

I am a system administrator and i have been asked to setup a Cloud Lab where following will be covered.

What I would like to know is what is the minimum number of hardware for servers, storage and networking is recommended to run this lab.

The courses taught are Open Nebula/ Eucalyptus, Globus Toolkit and would be approximately 60 hours. Maximum student capacity is 30 at a time.

Few Topic which will be covered are

**GRID COMPUTING LAB:**

S/W used : Globus Toolkit  (http://toolkit.globus.org/toolkit/news.html#209)

1. Develop new OGSA-compliant Web Service.
2. Using Apache Axis develop a Grid Service.
3. Develop secured applications using basic security mechanisms available in Globus Toolkit.
4. Develop a Grid portal, where user can submit a job and get the result. Implement it with and without GRAM concept.

**CLOUD COMPUTING LAB:**

S/W : Eucalyptus(http://www8.hp.com/in/en/cloud/helion-eucalyptus.html) or Open Nebula to achieve

1. Find procedure to run the virtual machine of different configuration. Check how many virtual machines can be utilized at particular time.
2. Find procedure to attach virtual block to the virtual machine and check whether it holds the data even after the release of the virtual machine.
3. Find procedure to install storage controller and interact with it.
4. Find procedure to set up the one node Hadoop cluster.
5. Mount the one node Hadoop cluster using FUSE.